# OCS Inventory integration in iTop Combodo

Tags: linux, inventory, ocs

i have a big problem with the integrations in iTop by Combodo, I hope anybody can help me :)

To my Problem...

I have two servers with Linux Ubuntu 18.04LTS, one has itop installed and the other ocs inventory, both have their own mysql database. I want to integrate the inventory into itop and have already tried the "Component details from OCS" tool.
Here's the link: https://store.itophub.io/en_US/products/itop-ocsng

I also installed everything normally and entered the IP of the OCS inventory into the config file of itop.

but it doesn't work at all, if i use the wrong connector, somebody has made some experiences, because for me itop as well as the ocs inventory are new territory. it would be great if somebody can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello there! I feel like this question would be a better fit for https://serverfault.com/ which is the "StackOverflow" for sysadmins. I suggest you try there

Comment: Hey Thank you for your tip, i will try it on serverfault :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [Data collector for OCS Inventory NG](https://store.itophub.io/en_US/products/ocsng-data-collector) which is a prerequisite to the "Component details from OCS" you mentioned. Once downloaded follow the tutorial to setup the synchronization on [this page](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?hide%5Bsidebar%5D=1&referer%5Bid%5D=store&referer%5Bpath%5D=%2Fen_US%2Fproducts%2Focsng-data-collector&id=extensions:ocsng-data-collector#requirements) of the documentation.